# Disable onbeforeunload in Firefox via extension or profile

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, firefox-profile

I am using Firefox to automatically navigate and capture screenshots from various websites. Some of these websites use the `onbeforeunload` event to capture a user's attention before leaving a page.

Right now, this prevents my script from navigating to the next URL and I have to run the following JS to redefine the event to do nothing, like below:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {};
```

I'd like to put this logic in the browser and not to deal with a bunch of edge-cases in my code. Ideally keeping Javascript enabled, whilst blocking this event (possibly others) on all pages the browser visits.

Is this possible through a known extension or via Firefox profile settings?

Comment: Does blocking popups help? See [Pop-up blocker settings, exceptions and troubleshooting](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/pop-blocker-settings-exceptions-troubleshooting)

Comment: Blocking popups doesn't help with these alert-like notifications.